# Fixing CTRL-* in vim under GNU screen

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gnu-screen

When running vim under GNU screen, I'm finding that combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with the arrow and Pg* keys don't work as expected.

I'm using the Ubuntu 10.10 `vim-gnome` package.

On a different machine, also running Ubuntu, this did work without problems; unfortunately I don't have that configuration available to me now.

There is a related question here: [How to fix Ctrl + arrows in Vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-to-fix-ctrl-arrows-in-vim)

However, the suggested solution there is to remap vim's keybindings to work with the terminal emulator, in that case PuTTY.  I don't recall doing anything of the sort, and suspect that there is a screen configuration option which will resolve this issue.

There's also a [thread](http://old.nabble.com/Problem-with-GNU-Screen-when-using-control-%2B-right-left-arrows-td26678971.html) on the gnu-screen mailing list which suggests that running vim via `$ TERM=xterm vim` is an appropriate fix or workaround.  This does work, but I'm a bit concerned that there might be side effects.  It also doesn't sound familiar enough to be the solution I set up on the other machine (if a solution was necessary).

Comment: +1 - I was having the same problem and - as you suggested - adding `term xterm` to my `~/.screenrc` file fixed it for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

As intuited stated in his update, adding `term xterm` to the `~/.screenrc` file seems to fix this problem.

Comment: Well.. yes, but I'm holding out for some sort of explanation as to why `screen` doesn't just propagate the `$TERM` environment variable instead of overriding it with `"screen"`.  Presumably there are some circumstances where it's important to have `$TERM == screen`.

Comment: @intuited: The reason Screen sets `TERM=screen` is that applications running inside are communicating inside a Screen terminal: the control sequences they send and receive are those of Screen, not those of whatever terminal Screen itself is being displayed. Since you can detach a Screen session and reattach it to a different type of terminal, this layer of indirection is necessary.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks, I suspected something like that.  What sorts of problems could arise from resetting it to `xterm`?

Comment: Not much, because xterm and screen are mostly compatible. But each has a few capabilities that the other one doesn't, and if you lie to applications, they might use a capability that doesn't actually work. Compare the output of `infocmp screen` and `infocmp xterm`, and the [screen escape sequences](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Virtual-Terminal) with the [xterm escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms). I don't have a breakdown to offer; most applications won't mind, but a few might behave annoyingly.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying problem is that the mapping done by `screen` between the actual terminal (identified by the `TERM` environment variable outside `screen`) and the emulation within `screen` is incomplete.

If you happen to test it (using [vttest](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html) or [tack](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tack.html)), you may notice deficiencies for

- colors
- special keys

Attempting to fix these problems by setting `term` in `.screenrc` has the drawback that it works only for a given actual-terminal, and is not portable to other terminal implementations.  The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Term) notes

> The use of the term command is discouraged for non-default purpose.

There is another solution (with a different drawback), using this feature from `screen` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Termcap):

> When screen tries to figure out a terminal name for itself, it first looks for an entry named **screen.*term***, where ***term*** is the contents of your `$TERM` variable. If no such entry exists, screen tries `screen` (or `screen-w`, if the terminal is wide (132 cols or more)). If even this entry cannot be found, `vt100` is used as a substitute.

ncurses provides several useful alternate terminal descriptions for this case, e.g., [screen.xterm-new](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-screen_xterm-new), to repair problems in screen's mapping.
In practice, I use `TERM=xterm-new`, and when running screen, get a usable mapping of function keys.

Referring back to screen's `term` setting, in testing you may notice that there are *still* problems with the mapping, which are addressed in these alternatives.  If it were possible to get an accurate terminal description using `term`, these alternatives would be simple aliases to `screen`.  They are not.

ncurses does *not* provide `screen.xterm` (sic) because:

- `TERM=xterm` is misused widely for terminal emulators which differ from xterm; adding this mapping would only aggravate that situation (see for example [Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic) in the ncurses FAQ)
- the alternative name `screen.xterm` is less likely to be installed on remote systems (see change comment from [June 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20150627) in the terminal database).

On the whole, however, using the alternate names is an improvement over using `term` in your `.screenrc`: it solves more problems than it creates.  The reverse is true of the `term` setting.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of other ways to set the terminal which work in running processes:

- In a running screen instance, pressing `^A`-`:` and issuing the command `term xterm` will cause *newly opened* screens under that instance to start with their `$TERM` environment variable set to `xterm`; this will in turn propagate to invoked `vim` instances.  These vim instances will display proper behaviour with regard to CTRL-combos; I've not yet discovered any side effects of this strategy.  This command does not affect existing screens.  This command can of course be used in a `~/.screenrc` file, so it's possible that this method was used on the other machine.
- In a running vim instance, the command `set term=xterm` will make CTRL-combos work in that vim instance.  This has the side effect of disconnecting the X clipboard (i.e. `@*` and `@+`) for reasons that I do not yet understand.  Interestingly, the clipboard side effect also happens when the command `:set term=screen` is executed in a vim instance started with `$TERM=xterm`.

Comment: This answer was taken from the OP's updates. All I did was to reformat and reword a little bit.