# Reassigning Ctrl + Arrow keys in Vim

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix Ctrl + arrows in Vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-to-fix-ctrl-arrows-in-vim)

Through the several tutorials and tips and tricks site about Vim, I think I happened to read that one can reassign a combination of keys in Vim.

I would have loved to switch between vim tabs more easily and quicker that typing `:tabn` or `:tabp` each time.

For the moment `Ctrl` + `Left` or `Right` arrow, makes me switch from `command mode` to `insert mode`, and pastes the character `c` or `d` according the arrow pressed.

So I plan to assign `Ctrl + Arrows` (Left Right) to `:tabn` `:tabp`

However as I am still relatively **really new** to Vim, I wonder if they may have a superuseful utility that I might not know about.

Am I safe to re-use them this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing what you are is because they're completely unassigned, and vim is processing the raw character sequence instead. Feel free to give them a useful purpose.

```
$ od -c <<< '<C-V><C-Left>'
0000000 033   [   1   ;   5   D  \n
0000007
$ od -c <<< '<C-V><C-Right>'
0000000 033   [   1   ;   5   C  \n
0000007
```